# What part of initramfs (Ubuntu) runs scripts/local?

Tags: ubuntu, initramfs

I'm trying to understand how Ubuntu 12.04's `initramfs` runs `scripts/local` and in what order. I don't see it in `init`. What line of code runs `scripts/local`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scripts/local` is only run when using a local root filesystem (as opposed to a network filesystem). The `BOOT` variable in the `init` script is set to either `local` or `nfs` accordingly, so the following line sources `scripts/local`:

```
$ grep -A1 Mounting init
log_begin_msg "Mounting root file system"
. /scripts/${BOOT}
```

Comment: How similar are the initramfs in other Linuxes?